# endpoints are always in UTC/GMT

Tags: r, time-series, xts, endpoints

I think the endpoints are generated by converting the index to UTC. I want the endpoints at change of every hour 9:00/10:00 etc ( or at my specific defined intervals, say at 9:30/10:30 etc).

In the below example object 'a' is UTC and endpoints are created at 4:55,5:55 etc, for the object 'b' its at 10:25,11:25 etc. I am looking for a solution that gives endpoints in specified way, irrespective of timezone.

Is there any simple mechanism to do so?

```
> head(a)
                       Open    High     Low   Close
2008-01-01 04:30:00 6114.05 6126.65 6111.35 6111.35
2008-01-01 04:35:00 6110.50 6130.65 6110.50 6128.90
2008-01-01 04:40:00 6128.70 6130.15 6123.15 6123.55
2008-01-01 04:45:00 6124.85 6131.90 6123.45 6131.55
2008-01-01 04:50:00 6132.20 6134.45 6128.70 6131.20
2008-01-01 04:55:00 6132.25 6134.85 6132.25 6134.45
> indexTZ(a)
   TZ 
"UTC" 
> a[endpoints(a,on="hours")]
                       Open    High     Low   Close
2008-01-01 04:55:00 6132.25 6134.85 6132.25 6134.45
2008-01-01 05:55:00 6136.70 6136.70 6132.15 6134.45
2008-01-01 06:55:00 6157.65 6157.65 6153.20 6154.25
2008-01-01 07:55:00 6155.65 6157.60 6155.00 6157.25
2008-01-01 08:55:00 6143.25 6143.90 6137.50 6138.05
2008-01-01 09:55:00 6150.95 6151.65 6147.50 6149.20
2008-01-02 04:55:00 6113.40 6120.90 6089.00 6089.00
2008-01-02 05:55:00 6086.15 6087.25 6068.80 6068.95
2008-01-02 06:55:00 6098.10 6108.25 6098.10 6105.85
2008-01-02 07:05:00 6107.40 6107.40 6093.70 6094.80
> head(b)
                       Open    High     Low   Close
2008-01-01 10:00:00 6114.05 6126.65 6111.35 6111.35
2008-01-01 10:05:00 6110.50 6130.65 6110.50 6128.90
2008-01-01 10:10:00 6128.70 6130.15 6123.15 6123.55
2008-01-01 10:15:00 6124.85 6131.90 6123.45 6131.55
2008-01-01 10:20:00 6132.20 6134.45 6128.70 6131.20
2008-01-01 10:25:00 6132.25 6134.85 6132.25 6134.45
> indexTZ(b)
            TZ 
"Asia/Kolkata" 
> b[endpoints(b,on="hours")]
                       Open    High     Low   Close
2008-01-01 10:25:00 6132.25 6134.85 6132.25 6134.45
2008-01-01 11:25:00 6136.70 6136.70 6132.15 6134.45
2008-01-01 12:25:00 6157.65 6157.65 6153.20 6154.25
2008-01-01 13:25:00 6155.65 6157.60 6155.00 6157.25
2008-01-01 14:25:00 6143.25 6143.90 6137.50 6138.05
2008-01-01 15:25:00 6150.95 6151.65 6147.50 6149.20
2008-01-02 10:25:00 6113.40 6120.90 6089.00 6089.00
2008-01-02 11:25:00 6086.15 6087.25 6068.80 6068.95
2008-01-02 12:25:00 6098.10 6108.25 6098.10 6105.85
2008-01-02 12:35:00 6107.40 6107.40 6093.70 6094.80
>
```

Thanks & Regds

Siva Sunku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`endpoints` always calculates offsets in UTC. There's nothing you can do to change that as an end-user. But you could work-around it by comparing the 1-hour endpoints with the 30-minute endpoints.

```
x <- .xts(1:12, seq(0, by=600, length.out=12), tzone="Asia/Kolkata")
x[endpoints(x, "hours")]
#                     [,1]
# 1970-01-01 06:20:00    6
# 1970-01-01 07:20:00   12
hourEndpointsTZ30 <- function(x) {
  h <- endpoints(x, "hours", 1)
  m <- endpoints(x, "minutes", 30)
  c(0, setdiff(m, h), last(m))
}
x[hourEndpointsTZ30(x)]
#                     [,1]
# 1970-01-01 05:50:00    3
# 1970-01-01 06:50:00    9
# 1970-01-01 07:20:00   12
```

Comment: Hello Joshua, Thanks a lot.